# Prevent the user from entering invalid values in number guessing game

Tags: python

The program below is just a high/low numbers game. One of the 4 criteria is having an error check to make sure the lower variable is in fact lower than the upper variable.

I've tried implementing it a few different ways to no success. I keep receiving a ValueError and I'm pretty certain it's because if I enter 10 as the "lower" variable and 1 as the "upper" variable, `randint` is trying to call `randint(10, 1)` instead of prompting the user an error and to reenter the numbers. I've tried a separate loop and `if` statements.

```
import random

seedVal = int(input('What seed should be used? '))
random.seed(seedVal)


lower = int(input('Enter lower bound. '))
upper = int(input('Enter upper bound. '))
answer = random.randint(lower, upper)


while True:
    guess = int(input('What is your guess? '))
    if guess < lower or guess > upper:
        print('Please enter a guess between lower bound and higher bound.')
    elif guess == answer:
        print('You got it!')
        break
    elif guess > answer:
        print('Nope, too high.')
    else:
        print('Nope, too low.')
```

Comment: Use a try-except statement. Here is a useful tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NIWwJbo-9_8&t=5s

Comment: You appear to have understood the concept of `if` conditions and `while True`. You need to apply both before calling `randint`

Comment: Essentially you need to use the same techniques that you have already used to implement the game logic, but instead with the two bounds the user has entered.

Comment: To insure lower <= upper, you can just use: `lower, upper = min(lower,upper), max(lower, upper)` before `answer = randint(lower, upper)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just do:-

```
valid_numbers = False
while not valid_numbers:
    lower = int(input('Enter lower bound. '))
    upper = int(input('Enter upper bound. '))
    if lower > upper:
        print("the lower value should be smaller than the upper value.")
        continue
    else:
        break

random.randint(lower, upper)
```

Answer (score -1):

You may want to use [Exception handling](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html). Simply raise an exception if values are not right, catch it and print message. Or catch the following error if this sequence is permited by default.
Regards